# Compile FTDI kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, serial-port, kernel-module, ftdi

I'm trying to add the usb to serial port driver to my arch linux arm device, and I noticed that the kernel source tree already includes the source files for the FTDI driver, located in:

drivers/usb/serial, there exists the ftdi_sio.c and ftdi_sio.h files.

When I navigate to kernel/drivers, I cannot find the ftdi_sio.ko module anywhere.

How do I build the ftdi kernel module and include it to boot so I can have usb to serial port capability on my arch linux arm?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237632/cross-compile-ftdi-vcp-driver-for-embedded-linux-arm

Comment: `ftdi_sio.ko` can't be found since it is compiled as part of linux kernel. i.e static module part of linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have the kernel source tree (from your distro package manager) on your arm device and you don't cross-compile :

```
make menuconfig
```

Navigate to : Device Drivers -> USB Support -> USB Serial Converter Support

And choose 'M'odule for `USB FTDI Single Port Serial Driver`

Exit, save changes and

```
make M=drivers/usb/serial/
make modules_install
```

Comment: Thanks, those steps worked. If I want to boot from a uImage with the included driver now, how would I proceed to do that? Would I then run make uImage after make modules_install? I tried doing that and it didn't work.

Comment: basically, `make modules_install` should do the necessary stuff. it should copy the generated .ko in /lib/modules/kernel-version/ and runnig `depmod`, so if you build with the same sources as current running kernel, it's ok.

Comment: I'm actually cross-compiling, so what I've done is: make ARCH=arm menuconfig, choose 'M'odule for USB FTDI, make M=drivers/usb/serial ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/z3/bin/arm- , then: INSTALL_MOD_PATH=<path> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/z3/bin/arm modules_install . And all I have to do now is u-boot from the uImage again? (no need to re-compile and build a new uImage?)

Comment: How do I depmod for my target system?

Comment: you can try to copy only ftdi_sio.ko on your target. And then `insmod ftdio.ko` (ensure that usbcore and usbserial are loaded before). It's hard to say you how to reinstall whole kernel without knowing your target and environment. And I don't want to brick your board :)

Comment: thank you so much! Your initial suggestion in your answer worked. I just had to add the ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE env variables, and specify the INSTALL_MOD_PATH. Afterwards, insmod both usbserial.ko and ftdi_sio.ko. I'd definitely upvote your answer if I had enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the .config:

```
make ARCH=arm menuconfig
```

Make and install modules:  `make modules`  and  `make modules_install`

Don't forget:  `insmod usbserial.ko`  and  `insmod ftdi_sio.ko`  if you need to, and  `depmod -a`  to have them load after a power cycle.